# How is Kanojo used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I know Kanojo can be used to refer to her or also mean girlfriend. I found this sentence and was curious

甲矢もねじれの親友として彼女と想いが通じ合っている様子が描かれていた

In this sentence, how is it being used and what is it saying exactly? If it's used as "her' does it mean intimacy or not?

Comment: I mean, first of all, what is the sentence saying? Context is from this description: http://comiaca.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/05/02/215749

Comment: It's very difficult to answer this kind of question since it's not clear what parts of the sentence you already understand. Perhaps you could try posting what you think the sentence says as a translation and we could give you better answers based on that.

Comment: @Ben I understand it's saying something like she's trying to communicate feelings with her or something. is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the context you provided, this 彼女 is simply "she", and it refers to ねじれ. She is clearly described as 甲矢's 親友 ("close friend"), so there is no romantic indication at least in this sentence.

> 甲矢もねじれの親友として彼女と想いが通じ合っている様子が描かれていた。
>
> (very literally) As for Koya, too, as Nejire's close friend, the scene where he had a mutual understanding with her was depicted.
>
> → [The manga] also depicted the scene where Nejire and his close friend Nejire have understood each other.

Comment: I was wondering, how is omoi used in this context? Does it mean love/romantic implication?

Comment: @Zain It depends on the context, but if there is no indication about love in the context, this 想い is simply "feeling", "compassion", "sympathy", etc.

Comment: why do you say there is no love indication? and how do you know  her refers to kenranzaki and not nejire?

Comment: @Zain I do not know the story of 僕のヒーローアカデミア at all. If you already know Koya and Kenranzaki are in love with each other, this 想い can be "love". Otherwise, it's not "love". That’s what "it depends on the context" means.

Comment: Is 想い refering to feelings between koya and kenranzaki or koya and nejire?

Comment: @Zain Oh, I'm sorry, I did not know Nejire is a female character! Then this 彼女 may refer to her.

Comment: Based on that, then Is 想い/phrase communicate feelings/thoughts used in a romantic sense or not? It uses the word best friend earlier, so does that mean anything?

Comment: @Zain Assuming this 彼女 refers to ねじれ, she is clearly described as 甲矢’s "close friend", so I see no reason to believe there is a romantic indication at least in this sentence. It just says Koya and Nejire are close friends and understand each other well.

Comment: I see but as I asked earlier, does't 想い usually mean love or something/ isn't the phrase communicate feelings mainly used in a romantic way?

Comment: @Zain No, 想い does not necessarily imply love. See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18375/5010

Comment: ah, so in this case, it just says they understand each other? Then why not use 思おもい cuz I read the other implies special emotion

Comment: @Zain See the link. Basically 想い is merely a poetic/profound variation of 思い. While it is often used in love songs, it can be used in other contexts. (BTW I fixed my answer according to your comment. Does that make sense now?)

Comment: Ah, so to clarify, in this context, it doesn't mean love?

Comment: @Zain You're right. Their relationship is described as 親友, which is very different from 恋人 in the first place.